# CORS / Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, apache, http, cors

I have set up an API using php, so that other web sites can query a DB on one of my server. When I want to make a test with a client page, I get this:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.example.net/my.php?fx=221&ix=603. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

.... .......
Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing
```

I understand, according to [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin), that I need to specify who is allowed to use the API.

Adding something like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://amazing.site
```

But what is less clear is where I should add this.

Is it at the apache server level? Or is it in my php page on the server side? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a header. See: https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Comment: add that header to the script targeted by the ajax request.. ie: in your PHP api pages before any output is sent to the browser

Comment: You can set this header in Apache too but within PHP is perhaps easier and more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, I added the header in the document mentioned by KIKO Software in my PHP file. It works.

Answer (score 3):

In Apache/conf/httpd.conf add code of below:

```
<IfModule headers_module>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://amazing.site"
</IfModule>
```

Make sure you have to uncomment of "LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so" in the same file.

You also can do it in every php file top:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://amazing.site");
```